# django admin raw_id opens with ?e=1 on django 1.6.x

Tags: python, django

I have developed a Scrum Based Team Management System on django (mostly admin) and everything works fine, after I upgraded to 1.6.x, raw_id opens with ?e=1 querystring and popups opens in edit mode.

My source code address is 
https://github.com/serj1975/tms

and I have a issue on this at 
https://github.com/serj1975/tms/issues/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution.
The problem was after I developed my apps on django 1.5, I ran `collectstatic` command and it fills my static folder with current version static files.
When I upgrade my solution with higher version (1.6) and started testing it, the problem I mentioned raised. After I removed all static files and add needed files one by one I found the reason.